# Highly Responsive Image using CSS only

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to make the images really responsive so that they fit into a square no matter what.
For example:

http://prntscr.com/87jey9
(sorry for the crappy image, couldnt upload images here due to low rep.)

---

Basically, the image should center itself, displaying the maximum part of the image that can be shown in a square. I dont want empty white spaces in the cropped square images.

I tried this using jquery and even succeeded, but i missed out that it wouldnt work properly if the page had more than one images.

```
$(window).on('load resize',squarifyImage);
function squarifyImage(){
    var cw = $('.square').width();
    $('.square').css({'height':cw+'px'});
    $('.square').css('overflow', "hidden");

    $('.thumb').css('width', '100%');
    var w = $('.thumb').width();
    var h = $('.thumb').height();

    if(w < h){
        $('.thumb').css('width', '100%');
        w = $('.thumb').width();
        h = $('.thumb').height();
        var top = (((h - w)/2)*-1);
        $('.thumb').css('margin-top', top);
    } else {
        $('.thumb').css("width", "");
        $('.thumb').css('height', '100%');
        w = $('.thumb').width();
        h = $('.thumb').height();
        var left = (((w - h)/2)*-1);
        $('.thumb').css('margin-left', left);

    }
}
```

The HTML is like,

```
<div class="square">
    <img class="thumb" src="testing.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

---

How do i do it using CSS only?

Comment: If you are looking for CSS only solution, what is the purpose of jQuery tag???

Comment: a better jQuery solution is also welcome

Comment: What about including Bootstrap CSS and then just giving the image the class `class="img-responsive"` http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Answer (score 1):

you can do this if you can set the `image` as `background-image` of the `square` through css and then use `background-size: cover` to achieve what you want.

```
<div class="square">
</div>

.square {
background-image: url('testing.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
}
```

***Alternatively***, use this css if you want to use `image` tag..

```
.square {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.square img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

now you can use the `img` tag.
[Fiddle demo to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/b8acx116/1/), I was currently not having suitable image to help you demonstrate but if you will see the image separately and find and assume the middle portion (roughly) and then see in the square box you will find that middle portion is only viewed. This is compatible with all major browsers even on older ones.

Comment: how do i do it for multiple images on a single page? i want different images in different divs

Answer (score 0):

Tried using the image tag's width and height attributes?
That would not crop your image, but resize it to the specified dimensions.

```
<img class="thumb" src='testing.jpg" height="50" width="50">
```

**UPDATE:**

So if you need to maintain the aspect, you can style the image with the CSS's clip property, something like this:

```
img {
    clip: rect(<top>,<right>,<bottom>,<left>);
}
```

The top, bottom, left and right are the respective offsets from the border of the original image.

**Note:** The clip property only works with position: absolute or position: fixed, so you need to add the desired in the image's CSS as well.

Its a bit tricky to manage the offsets for sure. You may have a look at this link for a better understanding of this property:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/

I hope this is what you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Do you specifically want to show just a part of the image according to your dimensions?

Comment: I dont want to alter the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS only why not try the viewport units.

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1qmn1bcz/)

HTML:

```
<img id="img1" src="http://metroui.org.ua/images/css-logo.png" />
```

css:

```
#img1{width:50vw; height:30vh;}
```

When the screen is resized the image will resize with it.

[Browser support viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)